# PyCharm 2.5 TestRunner cannot import specific module

Tags: django, pycharm

I've upgraded to PyCharm 2.5 and in the meantime upgraded `django-templated-email` to version 0.4.3.

Now, Django unit tests do not longer work through PyCharm, as I'm getting the error `ImportError: cannot import name send_templated_mail` in the test console output.

When running the same test in the console, this error does not appear. I have the feeling that it has something to do with `send_templated_email` being part of `templated_email\__init__.py` (I vaguely remember a similar issue once, but cannot for the life of me remember how I fixed it).

The settings in the test dialog are:

```
Target: <django app name>
Custom settings: <path to dev settings>
Environment variables: PYTHONPATH: <path as set in virtualenv>
Python interpreter: <virtualenv Python interpreter>
Interpreter options: None
Working directory: <path to Django project (where manage.py resides)>
```

The strange thing is that the code inspection inside the IDE does not complain and loads the `templated_email` module correctly through `from templated_email import send_templated_mail`.

I'm using Windows 7, and my Django app is running inside a virtualenv (which is correctly being recognized by PyCharm).

Comment: Is it working in the terminal (console in windows I guess)? Can you try to force to import the correct function in your test settings? Did you mean test settings here?: Custom settings: <path to dev settings>

Comment: Could be that the version of Django you're using is not supported by your older version of PyCharm. Perhaps you should update?

Comment: I had an issue like this, the problem in my case was that I was a using a differente virtualenv in pycharm than in console. Could that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to version 4.5.x if you haven't already. It fixes lots of bugs and has several improvements.

Also, if you think this is a bug in PyCharm, check out their bug tracking/filing site:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues